# jQuery selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

ive been trying to figure out why my JavaScript code will not work. The alert works fine, but when I try to write in a div it does nothing. What am I doing wrong? Ive been trying to google the answer, but that has not been too helpful.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="gamejavascript.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>  

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="gameStyle.css">

<title>Text Adventure RPG</title>   

</head>

<body>
<p>hey  </p>
    <div id="eventWindow">
        <div id="title">Black Forest</div>
        <div id="eventContent">You have entered the black forest. Lucky you!</div>
    </div>
    <div id="itemList">Hey hey hey </div> 

    <div id="userStat"> </div> 

</body>

</html>
```

My javascript is

```
$("p").append("HEY HEYH YEYEHE."); 
alert("You madam are a horse!");
$("#userStat").html("Hey baby"); 



/* var user = function(attack,health)
{
this.attack = attack; 
this.health = health;
}; 

var player = new user(10,100); */
```

thank you so much for your help!

-Brent

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to put your JavaScript at the end of the page before the closing body tag or in the head and wrapped in a [document ready call](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Ex:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/vp4Xx/)** (placing code at end of document)

The way you have it now, you're trying to execute code on elements that don't yet exist.

Answer (score 5):

Wrap your code in [**document-ready handler**](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and assuming jquery is loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("p").append("HEY HEYH YEYEHE.");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In order jQuery to run properly, the html content should be loaded first. For this reason you should put your code in the document ready handler. Try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    // put your code here as it is 
});
```

Comment: How is this answer any different from Rimpy's or mine?

Comment: I explained also that the html content should be loaded dirst. You provided the code but not the reason for that change. I think that is the difference.

Comment: The last sentence in my answer explains the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you append a div using jQuery & then you try to use selector on that div then you need to use this syntax -

```
$('body').on('click', '.mydiv', function() {
     alert('ok');
});
```